# Js: elem.onclick works, elem2.onclick doesnt fire at all

Tags: javascript, android, webview, chromium

I'm stumped. I'm building a webapp for reading comics. Testing on Android 4.4.2 and Android L Dev preview (second edition, released this week)

The following code works:

```
var comicstack = document.createElement("div");
comicstack.className = "comicstack";
comicstack.comic = comic;
comicstack.onclick = function() {
    loggr.log(" > Click: "+ this.comic);
    site.hcomic.init(this.comic);
}
$(".comicstack_container").append(comicstack);
```

But when I hide the section that holds these elements and draw new ones in another section (done by site.hcomic.init), the onclick just doesn't fire

```
var comicstack = document.createElement("div");
comicstack.className = "comicstack";
comicstack.comic = series;
comicstack.issue = issue;
comicstack.onclick = function() {
    loggr.log("HEY I'M BEING CLICKED BUT I'M IGNORING IT HAHA!");
}
$(".comicstack_container").append(comicstack);
```

What is the world am I doing wrong?

(Btw, the loggr.log() function is a wrapper around console.log, long story)

UPDATE:

The following code (kind of) works (the onclick fires but I can't get comicstack.comic and -.issue this way..?)

```
$(".comicstack").on("click",function(evt){ 
    loggr.log(evt.currentTarget.comic); // returns 'undefined'
    loggr.log(evt.currentTarget.className); // returns 'comicstack'
});
```

I. Don't. Get. It.

Comment: You should also show how you're adding the element to the DOM, and how the element is presented. An element can only receive a "click" if it's properly visible and if no other element is stealing the events.

Comment: I'm using jquery to append it to a container. I can't really show how it's presented but it's a DIV with an image inside it (the cover of the comic). Nothing is blocking it. I'll also add my current solution but it's ugly because jQuery.on() does some weird stuff with 'this', evt.originalTarget.target returns the top element, not the element that the on() is binded to